# Vanishing sum of roots of unity with fixed weight

Tags: nt.number-theory

Consider the set
$S_n(d) = \{(x_1, \cdots ,x_n) \in \mathbb{C}^n \mid 1 + x_1+\cdots +x_n = 0, x_i^d=1 \text{ for all } i=1,\dots,n.\}$

Many papers which I found consider the conditions on $n$ and $d$ for non-emptyness of $S_n(d)$, but I want to count the EXACT number of solutions with each fixed $n$.

(For example, the size of $S_7(d)$ as a function in $d$.)

Are there any known results?

Comment: Of course, there is no exact formula for $|S_n(d)|$ as a function of $n$ and $d$. What you probably want is an asymptotic equivalent as a function of $d$ for a fixed $n$, and also a procedure (algorithm) to compute this number exactly as a function of $d$, for any given (small) $n$. This is made possible by a theorem of H.B. Mann (*Mathematica* **12**, 1965): the subset of $\bigcup_d S_n(d)$ consisting of tuples $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ with no vanishing subsum, is finite (and bounded by $\exp(cn^2)$). Given this, it can be shown inductively by considering a minimal zero-subsum of $\sum_i x_i$ [tbc]

Comment: [cont.] ...that $|S_n(d)| \sim c(n)d^{n/2}$ (or so...) as $d \to \infty$, where $c(n)$ is a certain combinatorial number which you can determine exactly. (The vast majority of contributions arise when $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ are roughly partitioned into pairs of opposite roots of unity.)

Comment: I should also say that for a given $n$, the finite set of solutions in Mann's theorem is effectively determinable.